# Intellij IDEA: не могу собрать проект Maven

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven, jar

Есть проект maven в Intellij IDEA 14, есть файлик pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>testId</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>test</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

что нужно сделать, чтобы собрать исполняемый jar файл, как это сделать с самой IDEA, что я делаю не так, что нужно нажать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В меню выбираете `Build -> Build Artifacts..`. В появившемся списке выбираете артифакт и нажимаете на `Build`. В корне проекта появится директория `out`. Там будет ваш jar.

Answer (score 0):

Я посмотрел, перед этим нужно в `File -> Project Structure -> Artifact` настроить предполагаемые `jar`,  а потом уже лезть в `Build -> Build Artifactжно в File -> Project Structure`.